# Add border and alignment header from Grid control to export excel

Tags: vb.net, export-to-excel, gridcontrol

can anyone help me, i have a problem about export file to excel from GridControl using vb.net. i use function ***ExportToExcelOld*** `GridList.ExportToExcelOld(SaveFileDialog1.FileName.ToString)`
but i don't know source code for add border cell and alignment center for title. please give me solution.

This screen shoot my  [Source Code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HnDFo.png)

Thanks.

Comment: Please post the relevant portion of your current code, it will be easier to picture where to add the necessary code you are asking for. Also review http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: sorry for that, i already update my post with screen shoot my source code. thanks